# Missing space in SEDE tutorial text

Tags: bug, data-explorer

There's a missing space between the **x** and "to" in the [SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/intro-to-queries) (when viewed on my Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64):

[image: Screenshot showing this text: "Click the X to return to the main list.) You'll notice that not all tables in the composer have the icon.". The error reported is the word "the" and the "X" have no space seperating them with medium-sized imgur image]

Comment: No repro on FF 95.2.0. Could repro on Chrome 96.0.4664.104 (although it's not quite as bad as in your case).  Both tests on Android 10

Answer (score 3):

While I [can't reproduce the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhxAz.png) on Chrome/Win10 or Firefox/Win10 in my testing adding a `&nbsp;` directly after the icon doesn't change much for me locally either but I expect the Android Webview might not collapse white-space when it is a non-breaking-white-space one. That would fix the issue on your device / setup.

This [pull-request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/118) had the proposed change.

But when Nick kindly tested that change it turned out to not solve the issue. It needed extra CSS for that work on Mobile Chrome:

```
[class^="icon-"] {
    margin-right: .3em;
}css
```

but that lead to a much wider space on all other browsers.

I'm not ready yet to support minor glitches with per browser tweaks. Until someone else has a better solution this stays [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), sorry.

Do not allow for 6 to 8 weeks to have the PR merged and deployed.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a collapsing whitespace issue as both spaces are still present, the issue is that it doesn't offer enough room for the icons: [see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH932.jpg), you can clearly see both spaces are still there, in both the highlight and the copy result.

Comment: @Nick hmm, okay. Maybe I need to add the `fa-fw` on the icon as well then, as suggested here: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons ?  Any better options?

Comment: I have noticed that on _first_ page load it works successfully, it's only on subsequent reloads that the issue appears. Clearing the cache fixes the issue, but then reloading makes it [the issue] appear again. Hazarding a guess it appears to be related to the `[class^="icon-"]` rule `*margin-right:.3em` only applying on first load.

Comment: Oh nice. I picked a bug that is basically a browser glitch. I hoped for a better Saturday  ...

Comment: If you have any thoughts feel free to give me a ping on discord, I've set up a local instance of the SEDE help page so I can edit it and test changes on mobile.